# LibGDX Repercussions of Eclipse no longer being supported for Android Dev? Should I still bother with Eclipse, or learn Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I'm a grade 12 student excited to make an android game over the summer. I've used LibGDX once before, for my Grade12 CompSci. final project. I now have some experience with LibGDX, and coded on Eclipse, which I am also now comfortable with.

I recently learned that Eclipse is no longer supported (I think this news is like 2 years old?) for android game development. I am not exactly comfortable with Android Studio yet, it seems daunting.

I know they're both just java at heart, so I'm not quite sure why I find it so daunting. Should I stick to Android Studio and learn about it, and android game dev through the IDE, or stick to Eclipse? What are the repercussions of Eclipse no longer being supported? Is it much harder to test my code? Is deploying to the app store harder? Is there limited functionality, like perhaps I can't control the back, home, etc. features?

This information would help me a lot. Sorry if the question is opinionated, but my base question really isn't; what are the repercussions of the fact that Eclipse is no longer supported as an official IDE?

Thanks so much, I'd really appreciate it! I'm a beginner, so sorry if it's a dumb question x.x